# Можно ли разделить файлы svg спрайта и index.html

Tags: html, css

Я создал svg спрайт но он мне мозолит глаза в основном файле html я бы хотел вынести все спрайты в отдельный файл, а использовать картинки в файле html можно ли это сделать без применения gulp и других сборщиков проектов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Зависит от того, как именно и для каких целей вы собираетесь их использовать

Comment: Для использования svg картинок. Ими я естественно хочу управлять через css так что какой-нибудь тег img не подойдет

Comment: Попробуй для вывода воспользоваться `<svg><use xlink:href="/sprite.svg#id"></use></svg>`. В спрайте должен быть указан соответствующий `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать так. Создал файл sprite.svg поместил туда полностью весь спрайт, добавил каждому элементу уникальный id, а в самом коде использовал

```
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="img/sprites.svg#id элемента который нужен"></use>
</svg>
```

Все работает и теперь лишний код глаза не мозолит